# How to capture Camera frames of all supported resolutions?

Tags: ios, swift, resolution, avcapturesession

Now I'm trying to figure out a way to capture camera frames of all supported resolutions concurrently.

For example, I need to capture camera frames for both resolutions `(640x480, 1920x1080)`.

The thing is, I've failed to add multiple `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` instances to `AVCaptureDeviceInput` per required resolution.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: What does "capture camera frames of all supported resolutions concurrently" mean?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. So I'm going to capture frames of various resolutions. 640x480 frame would be used to preview camera. And higher res frame would be used to recognize something.

Answer (score -1):

For sorry output ignores width/height keys , so you may have to declare 2
 sessions with different presets

```
lowSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
highSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080
```

Comment: Thank you @Sh_Khan. One Question. Can I add multiple capture sessions for a camera device? Do they output equal frames (except resolution)?